# Create a class which stores a dictionary and sets object properties on dictionary value changes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
Feedback = {'TV1power' : 0, 'TV2power' : 0, 'TV3power' : 0}
```

When TV1power is 1 i want to change an object property ie. `Powerbutton.SetState(1)`

I've been playing with the following but not having much luck as i'm fairly new to python:

```
FeedbackDict = {'TV1power' : 0, 'TV2power' : 0, 'TV3power' : 0}

class Feedback(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value): 
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value) 
        if name == 'TV1power': 
            if value == 1:
                Powerbutton.SetState(1)
                FeedbackDict[name] = 1

TVFeedback = Feedback()
TVFeedback.TV1power = 1
```

I know there must be a better way to store a dictionary in a class and on a value change do something.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DYZ pretty sure he wants a method that updates a value in his dictionary, I'm just unsure what `name` and `value` are since he is creating `TVFeedback` with neither

Comment: @vash_the_stampede On the contrary, it is perfectly clear what `name` and `value` are, but if someone wants to get an answer, they must ask an explicit question. That's how SO works.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede They are the parameters to `__setattr__()`.

Comment: @DYZ I see i never used the `__setattr__` that makes this simpler

Comment: My question is: Is there a better way to do this. Particularly as my dictionary grows I end up needing a lot of if statements in the class.

Comment: You might want to check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?). It's not set in stone, but it's a great set of naming and formatting guidelines for writing consistent, readable Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get out of having a bit of extra code for each type of feedback, but if the arguments are consistent, you could separate the feedback types themselves out into something like this.

```
FEEDBACK_SETTINGS = {
    "tv_1_power" : {
        "default": 0,
        "callable":  print,
    },
    # ...
}


class Feedback(object):
    tv_1_power = None
    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        for name, info in FEEDBACK_SETTINGS.items():
            self.__setattr__(name, info["default"])

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        FEEDBACK_SETTINGS[name]["callable"](value)

feedback = Feedback()
feedback.tv_1_power = 1
```

In this case, you'd have `Powerbutton.SetState` as the callable for the `tv_*_power` settings. I left that out so this would be a working, runnable example; this way you can see it call `print` when it sets that value on instantiation and then again when it's set manually.

*Edit: Updated to help readability and IDE inspection/completion at the expense of kind of repeating myself by defining the settings in both the dict and on the class.*

Comment: This is exactly what i was thinking! Now i dont have to have a heap of elif or if statements within my class checking for each device name. Thank you very much! This will help as occasionally i'll have 30+ devices with multiple states to keep track of for every device.

Comment: Do i have to declare each object as none and do the __init__? If i dont won't they just be created as i set them?

Comment: I've run some trial and error and discovered if i dont declare none and initialise then try and return a result for an undeclared object it exceptions.
Thank you very much for this!